# How to get dragged text position MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to insert tag next to specific text.
I was get a knowhow to insert tag next to text..

It is to use `Setsel()` and `ReplaceSel()`.

example,

```
char str = "< name >";
m_richedit.Setsel( position of start dragging of text, end position ) 
m_richedit.ReplaceSel( str, TRUE )
```

but, I don't know how to get position of start dragging of text in richEdit.

Is there anybody who has an idea?
Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to replace a string that the user selects with the mouse with your tag? You do not need to call Setsel() as this will be done by the user with the mouse. You probably mean to handle EN_SELCHANGE message from the richEdit control and then call GetSel to find out what is selected. You probably also mean to add a tag next to the selection and not in place of the selection.

Comment: What do you mean by "dragging of text"? Is the user dragging text from the edit control somewhere else? Or from somewhere else to the edit control?

Comment: I'm sorry. When I select text (by mouse or input shift + direction key + homekey ) and enter accelerator key, I wish to insert other text beside to selected text. For example, when I select "John" text, as result make following: "<name>John</name>".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the appropriate accelerator key like they explain here: [Adding accelerators(shortcuts) in MFC - HOW?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702437/adding-acceleratorsshortcuts-in-mfc-how) . Then in the handler of the accelerator key, use GetSelText, add your tags to the string you get and call ReplaceSel.